# adding jsp in jquery layout pane

Tags: jquery

I have my layout like following: 
The west pane comprises of few links on which when user clicks, corresponding jsp page should displayed in the center pane of the layout.... How can i achieve that an outside jsp page should be displayed in a particular pane; here center pane????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get the contents of the jsp page by making an AJAX call and inserting the response into an element in the layout pane.

you could also use an iframe and give its src the url of the jsp page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I have not used iframe ever... Can u gimme some reference example for this?

Comment: n also if you could tell me how to get the jsp contents through the ajax call... Thanks for d help...